# Как получить разницу между датами в минутах

Tags: python

Хочу получить разницу между датами в минутах. На выходе почему то у меня неправильное значение. Что не так?

```
currentdate = datetime.now()
dbdata = getUserLastPost(message.chat.id) #2020-04-25 11:02:26

lastdate = datetime.strptime(dbdata,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
raz = lastdate-currentdate
```

Comment: `"На выходе почему то у меня неправильное значение"` - укажите в вопросе какое значение вы считаете "правильным"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь методом [timedelta.total_seconds()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
In [6]: d1 = datetime.strptime('2020-04-25 11:02:26', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

In [7]: d2 = datetime.strptime('2020-04-25 12:12:12', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

In [8]: seconds = (d2 - d1).total_seconds()

In [9]: minutes = (d2 - d1).total_seconds() / 60

In [10]: seconds
Out[10]: 4186.0

In [11]: minutes
Out[11]: 69.76666666666667
```